# Django : send_mail HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, return, sendmail

I have a problem with return HttpResponseRedirect

the error is Page not found

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/

model.py

```
def on_post_save(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    print 'created'
    send_mail(u"demande_Expertise", 'Bonjour je souhaite obtenir les droits d acces de ce materiau', 'patrice.kerviel@gmail.com',
        [instance.categorie.expert.utilisateur.email])
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000")

else:
    if instance.etat=='0':
        send_mail(u"demande acceptée", u'Bonjour, votre demande est acceptée', u'patrice.kerviel@gmail.com',
                  [instance.user.email])
    elif  instance.etat=='1':
          send_mail(u"demande refusée", u'Bonjour, votre demande est refusée', u'patrice.kerviel@gmail.com',
                    [instance.user.email])
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                     #url(r'^$', main_page),
                     url(r'^$', mainView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
```

what is this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudn't return anything from `on_post_save` signal.  These `HttpResponseRedirect` responses are thrown out during saving of the model.

Show the code of the view in which you save the model instance.

**EDIT**: Ok, I see you view.  Change `success_url` of your view from `/home/` to `/`

```
class Demande_Expertise(CreateView):
    form_class = Demande_ExpertiseForm
    template_name = 'material/demande_expertise3.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

And don't forget to remove `return HttpResponseRedirect()` lines from `on_post_save` function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are a couple issues.

1. HttpResponseRedirect doesn't match any urlpatterns
2. More important, you don't return a response from a model

You could do something like this in your views.py:

```
def some_view(request):
  element = SomeModel(value=some_value, etc) #this has custom save actions
  if element.field == 'something:
  return redirect('homepage')
```

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but you can customize save actions in a model.  However, the view is where you should determine what templates or pages get served up.